# DispatchQueue.main.async {} in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I was wondering what happens if I call something asynchronously in main queue from viewDidLoad method. A little experiment showed me these results:

This code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    firstSelector()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.secondSelector()
    }
    for i in 1...10 {
        print(i)
    }
    thirdSelector()

}

func firstSelector() {
    print("First selector fired")
}

func secondSelector() {
    print("Second selector fired")
}

func thirdSelector() {
    print("Third selector fired")
}
```

Gives these prints:

```
First selector fired
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
Third selector fired
Second selector fired
```

So the last one method that was called is secondSelector. I think this is because main queue is serial and when I call asynchronously some method (secondSelector in this case) it returns immediately and waits until all other methods will be completed. After queue is free of tasks it completes method that I called asynchronously. Am I right in my thoughts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50727122/swift-threading-when-to-use-dispatchqueue-main-async

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I used to ask a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620128/block-main-thread-dispatch-get-main-queue-and-or-not-run-currentrunloop). Let me quote the important part of the answer I got:

> "Because the default runloop on the main thread has the special behaviour that, when run, it also processes for the main dispatch queue..."

When you do `dispatch_async` to a main thread, your block `{ self.secondSelector() }` gets scheduled to a main run loop. Since `viewDidLoad` method is already being executed by the main run loop, your dispatched block with be processed after `viewDidLoad` and all other (possible) blocks or methods that were scheduled before your block will be executed.

Keep in mind that your question is about behaviour of `dispatch_async` when you dispatch to the main queue and main run loop from the main thread. `viewDidLoad` has nothing to do with it - the only thing where it is relevant here, is that `UIViewController`'s lifecycle methods like `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` etc are all run on the main thread (processed by a main run loop). You will see the same behaviour with any method other than `viewDidLoad` given this method is run on a main thread. If you call dispatch_async from other thread you might be surprised by different results because in that case you will have two threads working at the same time (your other thread and a main thread to which you dispatched).