# Swift Threading: When to use DispatchQueue.main.async?

Tags: swift, multithreading, user-interface

I believe I understand what the dispatch queue is doing when I call it, but I'm not sure when exactly I should use it and what it's advantages are when I do use it.

If my understanding is correct, `DispatchQueue.main.async { // code }` will schedule the code contained within the closure to run on the main dispatch queue in an asynchronous manner. The main queue has the highest priority, and is typically reserved for updating UI to maximize App responsiveness.

Where I'm confused is: What exactly is the difference in updating UI elements within a dispatch queue closure versus just writing the code outside the closure in the same spot? Is it faster to execute the code in the body of a view did load method rather than sending it to the dispatch queue? If not, why?

Code Example:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateUI()
    }

}
```

Versus:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            updateUI()
        }
    }
}
```

Which one is will update the UI faster?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The primary use of `DispatchQueue.main.async` is when you have code running on a background queue and you need a specific block of code to be executed on the main queue.

In your code, `viewDidLoad` is already running on the main queue so there is little reason to use `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

But isn't necessarily wrong to use it. But it does change the order of execution.

Example without:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    func updateUI() {
        print("update")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("before")
        updateUI()
        print("after")
    }
}
```

As one might expect, the output will be:

> before
>   update
>   after

Now add `DispatchQueue.main.async`:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    func updateUI() {
        print("update")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("before")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            updateUI()
        }
        print("after")
    }
}
```

And the output changes:

> before
>   after
>   update

This is because the async closure is queued up to run after the current runloop completes.

Comment: How do we know which functions are or aren't run in the main queue?

Comment: `print("Is main queue: \(Thread.isMainThread)")`

Comment: An example where this is needed is when you're trying to seek an AVPlayer in the viewDidLoad. It needs to complete the function before it can seek so calling it in DispatchQueue.main.async will allow it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the exact situation discribed in your Question: `viewDidLoad()` calling `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

In my case I was wanting to modify Storyboard defaults prior to displaying a view.

But when I ran the app, the default Storyboard items were momentarily displayed. The animated segue would finish. And only THEN would the UI components be modified via the code in `viewDidLoad()`. So there was this annoying flash of all of the default storyboard values before the real values were edited in.

This was because I was modifying those controls via a helper function that always first dispatched to the main thread. That dispatch was *too late* to modify the controls prior to their first display.

So: modify Storyboard UI in `viewDidLoad()` *without* dispatching to the Main Thread. If you're already on the main thread, do the work there. Otherwise your eventual async dispatch may be too late.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330679/how-to-dispatch-on-main-queue-synchronously-without-a-deadlock