# Why my completionBlock never gets called in an NSOperation?

Tags: iphone, ios6, nsoperation

I've sublcassed an NSOperation and set my completionBlock but it seems to never enter even when the operation finishes. Here's my code:

A catalog controller class sets up the NSOperation:

```
- (void)setupOperation {
...

    ImportWordOperation *importWordOperation = [[ImportWordOperation alloc] initWithCatalog:words];
    [importWordOperation setMainObjectContext:[app managedObjectContext]];
    [importWordOperation setCompletionBlock:^{
        [(ViewController *)[[app window] rootViewController] fetchResults];
    }];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:importWordOperation];
    [importWordOperation release];
...
}
```

As you can see, I'm setting the completion block to execute a method on the main thread, in some other controller.

Then, in `main` my subclassed NSOperation class: `ImportWordOperation.m`, I fire-up the background operation. I even overrode `isFinished` iVar in order for the completion method to be triggered:

```
- (void)setFinished:(BOOL)_finished {
    finished = _finished;
}

- (BOOL)isFinished {
    return (self.isCancelled ? YES: finished);
}

- (void)addWords:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    NSError *error = nil;

    AppDelegate *app = [AppDelegate sharedInstance];

    NSManagedObjectContext *localMOC = [userInfo valueForKey:@"localMOC"];
    NSEntityDescription *ent = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Word" inManagedObjectContext:localMOC];
    for (NSDictionary *dictWord in [userInfo objectForKey:@"words"]) {
        Word *wordN = [[Word alloc] initWithEntity:ent insertIntoManagedObjectContext:localMOC];

        [wordN setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dictWord];
        [wordN release];
    }

    if (![[userInfo valueForKey:@"localMOC"] save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    [localMOC reset];

    [self setFinished:YES];
}


- (void)main {

    finished = NO;

    NSManagedObjectContext *localMOC = nil;
    NSUInteger type = NSConfinementConcurrencyType;
    localMOC = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:type];
    [localMOC setUndoManager:nil];
    [localMOC setParentContext:[self mainObjectContext]];

    if (![self isCancelled]) {
        if ([self.words count] > 0) {
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(addWords:) withObject:@{@"words":self.words, @"localMOC":localMOC}];
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove isFinished accessor methods, then the completion block gets called but way before `ImportWordOperation` finishes.

I've read code that I've found that uses its own completion block but then what's the use for the completion block in NSOperation subclasses anyway?

Any ideas or point to a similar solved situation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You've kind of fallen into a weird space between concurrent and non-concurrent `NSOperation` subclasses here. Typically, when you implement `main`, your operation is non-concurrent, and `isFinished` changes to `YES` as soon as `main` exits.

However, you've provided your own implementation of `isFinished`, and also coded it so that `isFinished` doesn't return `YES` until after `main` has exited. This makes your operation start to act like a concurrent operation in many ways - at least including the need to manually emit KVO notifications.

The quick solution to your problem is to implement `setFinished:` using `(will|did)ChangeValueForKey:` calls. (I also changed the ivar name to reflect naming prevailing naming conventions). Below is an `NSOperation` subclass that I believe accurately models your operation's workings, in terms of finishing in a concurrent fashion.

```
@implementation TestOperation {
    BOOL _isFinished;
}

- (void)setFinished:(BOOL)isFinished
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    // Instance variable has the underscore prefix rather than the local
    _isFinished = isFinished;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}

- (BOOL)isFinished
{
    return ([self isCancelled] ? YES : _isFinished);
}

- (void)main
{
    NSLog(@"%@ is in main.",self);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        sleep(1);
        [self setFinished:YES];
    });
}

@end
```

I'm not familiar with your requirements so perhaps you have a pressing need, but your operation would seem a more natural fit for a concurrent operation that uses `start` instead of `main`. I've implemented a small example that appears to be working correctly.

```
@implementation TestOperation {
    BOOL _isFinished;
    BOOL _isExecuting;
}

- (void)setFinished:(BOOL)isFinished
{
    if (isFinished != _isFinished) {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
        // Instance variable has the underscore prefix rather than the local
        _isFinished = isFinished;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    }
}

- (BOOL)isFinished
{
    return _isFinished || [self isCancelled];
}

- (void)cancel
{
    [super cancel];
    if ([self isExecuting]) {
        [self setExecuting:NO];
        [self setFinished:YES];
    }
}

- (void)setExecuting:(BOOL)isExecuting {
    if (isExecuting != _isExecuting) {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
        _isExecuting = isExecuting;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    }
}

- (BOOL)isExecuting
{
    return _isExecuting;
}

- (void)start
{
    NSLog(@"%@ is in start. isCancelled = %@", self, [self isCancelled] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    if (![self isCancelled]) {
        [self setFinished:NO];
        [self setExecuting:YES];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^ {
            sleep(1);
            [self setExecuting:NO];
            [self setFinished:YES];
        });
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: thanks!, it was the `main`/`start` method. I needed to implement `start` instead of `main`, as I need it to be concurrent. I changed that and adjusted KVO in setFinished and it worked!. I'm adding the `-cancel` method to round things up.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error while implementing an asynchronous subclass of `NSOperation`.

The Swift way of referencing key paths is with the `#keyPath` directive, so I was doing this (`_executing` and `_finished` are my internal variables):

```
self.willChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(Operation.isExecuting))
self._executing = false
self.didChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(Operation.isExecuting))

self.willChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(Operation.isFinished))
self._finished = true
self.didChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(Operation.isFinished))
```

Unfortunately, the `#keyPath` expressions above resolve to `"executing"` and `"finished"`, respectively, and we need to throw KVO notifications for `"isExecuting"` and `"isFinished"`. This is why the `completionBlock` is not getting invoked.

The solution is to hard code them as such:

```
self.willChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
self._executing = false
self.didChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")

self.willChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
self._finished = true
self.didChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
```